# symfony php bin console router match command fails and going in other location for path_info?

Tags: symfony-4.3

I've just installed new symfony4.3 skeleton and created one controller and when going to terminal and do fire following command :

`php bin/console router:match /blog`

Its shows error like 
[ERROR] None of the routes match the path "C:/Program Files/Git/blog"

Please find below image.

[image](https://prnt.sc/nzvimn)

Comment: This happens to me when running with Symfony 3.4 from Git Bash as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Symfony3 when running the command from `git bash terminal`. For me it worked to use `CMD terminal` instead.
Hope it helps.